# How to give a vector with magnitude as a legend in a plot?

Tags: python, plot, vector, legend, python-xarray

So I want to set a vector with magnitude as the `legend` for a vector plot, so that it can be used as a reference for the vector lengths. Here's the code that generates the vector plot given below.

```
D.mean(dim='TIME').plot.quiver(
    x="lon",
    y="lat",
    u="SOZOTAUX1", 
    v="SOMETAUY1",
    scale=0.37
)
ax.coastlines()
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(True)
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_visible(True)
```

[image: Plot]

Also adding a plot for reference. I want to produce the exact same result for the plot legend.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to write a label aside each quiver plotted on the graph?

Comment: @Colim No. I want to have one vector arrow with specific length representing a specific magnitude in the plot legend which can be taken as a reference. Just added a reference plot.

Comment: If your plotting package does Unicode, there are lots of Unicode right arrows.  `\u2192`, `\u2b62`, `\u27f6`.  You might have to print it first and get the calibrated length value.